# Python hashes don't match

Tags: python, md5

I am using Python to generate a C++ header file. It is security classified, so I can't post it here.

I generate it based on certain inputs and, if those don't change, the same file should be generated.

Because it is a header file which is #included almost everywhere, touching it causes a full build. So, if there is no change, I do not want to generate the file.

The simplest approach seemed to be to generate the file in `/tmp` then take an MD5 hash of the existing file, to see if it needs to be updated.

```py
existingFileMd5 = hashlib.md5(open(headerFilePath,  'rb').read())
newFileMd5 = hashlib.md5(open(tempFilePath,  'rb').read())
if newFileMd5 == existingFileMd5:
    print('Info:    file "' + headerFilePath + '" unchanged, so not updated')
    os.remove(tempFilePath)
else:
    shutil.move(tempFilePath, headerFilePath)
    print('Info:    file "' + headerFilePath + '" updated')
```

However, when I run the script twice in quick succession (without changing the inputs), it seems to always think that the MD5 hashes are different and updates the file, thus reducing build time.

There are no variable parts to the file, other than those governed by the input. E.g, I am not writing a timestamp.

I have had colleagues eyeball the two files and declare them to be identical (they are quite small). They are also declared to be identical by Linux's `meld` file compare utility.

So, the problem would seem to be with the code posted above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare md5 hashes of two files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873485/compare-md5-hashes-of-two-files-in-python)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, I suppose; the correct approach is the same in both cases, but the error is different here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to actually ask for the hashes. You're comparing two md5-hasher-thingies, not the hashes.

Call `digest` to get the hash as a `bytes` object, or `hexdigest` to get a string with a hex encoding of the hash:

```
if newFileMd5.digest() == existingFileMd5.digest():
    ...
```

Comment: D'oh! Obvious once you point it out. Invisible until you do.  In the meantime, I used `filecmp.cmp()`, which may well just wrap the MD5 digest comparison.