# Compare two files .txt and validate if all elements of file 1 is on the file 2

Tags: python

I wouldlike to compare 2 files and display if it's ok or not (validation).
Here a small picture to describe what I wouldlike to do :

[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KQRr.png)

```
def open_file_txt(file_name):  

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()

    return x

def validation(file_name1, file_name2):

    file1 = open_file_txt(file_name1)
    file2 = open_file_txt(file_name2)

    for elem in file1:
        for elem2 in file2:
            #### code
```

I don't know if I started well but I imagine structure like that...

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873485/compare-md5-hashes-of-two-files-in-python

Comment: In your example, you want to compare files row-wise. And each file's rows are sorted in alphabetical order, and are unique (no duplicates), hence e.g. `Test A, TestD, TestF` with newline separators instead of commas. So you can store them in a Python `set`, you don't even need `collections.Counter` (an item can't occur more than once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper method  to use is `set.issubset`.

```
set(file1).issubset(file2)
```

Note that issubset accepts a list (at least in python 3.7) so you only need to convert one list.

Answer (score 3):

`readlines()` returns a list so once you have both lists, you can get the elements that are common to both lists with `set(lst1).intersection(lst2)`. Futhermore, since you want to check if all elements of lst1 are in lst2, you can do `set(lst1).difference(lst2)` and make sure your result is empty as that returns the elements of lst1 that where not found in lst2.

In this example `lst1` and `lst2` are the two lists in from your `readlines()` calls.

Hope that helps.